# Need to block a 2Hz signal to a simple inverter

Tags: digital-logic, inverter, low-pass

I have to create a circuit to handle a signal that can be in one of three states:

high (3V)

low

2Hz square wave

The logic needs to be...

```
----------------
|  IN   |  OUT |
----------------
| high  | low  |
| low   | high |
| 2Hz   | high |
----------------
```

I have a nice simple circuit that covers the first two well, (simple inverter), but cant see any simple way to handle this 2Hz signal.

[image]

If possible, I need to do this discretely, without any ICs.

Comment: Please specify the maximum time to tell apart 2Hz from a static low/high.

Comment: The 2Hz square wave is symmetrical on/off, so it is roughly 250ms on, 250ms off. It doesn't matter if it takes a second or two for the circuit to detect the difference between the states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that a logic-level MOSFET has a threshold voltage of 2 volts, a circuit like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fj8WoR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

will (sort of) work.

The idea is that, with a time constant of .45 seconds, it will take .45 seconds for R3/C1 to charge up to just about 2/3 (e/3, actually)while the input is high, but C1 will discharge through D1 during the low phase, so M1 will never turn on.

This is not a great circuit, though, for various reasons.

1) The turn-on threshold for a MOSFET is not sharp, and varies with temperature, so the output will be neither sharp nor terribly precise.

2) For the components shown, the charge current is very small, so diode leakage may be a problem.

3) C1 will not discharge all the way to ground when the input is low, since the impedance of a diode increases as the voltage across it drops. Using a Schottky will improve this effect at the cost of increased leakage as commented on in 2).

Answer (score 1):

Making some assumptions, this will do what you ask. However, it might also do other things that you don't ask for.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f75ahw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the input is low, D1 will pull the gate down.

When the input is high, R2 will pull the gate up.

After the input has been low for a while (discharging C1), when it goes high, there will be some time delay before R2 has charged C1 enough to turn on M1. If this delay is greater than 250mS, but less than 1 second, then this circuit will do what you ask for, when given a 50% duty cycle 2Hz square wave.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to just low-pass your gate drive, but want some slightly better control over the behavior, then it sounds about like the following, where the retrig one-shot's output is inactive-high and active-low.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frVpxT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

1. Input is constant-HI and the retrig one-shot's output has relaxed to inactive-HI. Output will be LO.
2. Input is constant-LO and the retrig one-shot's output has relaxed to inactive-HI. Output will be HI.
3. Input is \$2\:\textrm{Hz}\$ and is triggering the one-shot repeatedly to hold an active-LO. Output will be HI.